# How do I change the perspective of a Matplotlib pie chart to make it look tilted?

Tags: matplotlib, pie-chart

I'm trying to change the perspective of a matplotlib pie chart.  I want it to look tilted like this (notice it looks like an oval): [image]

instead of flat (looks more like a circle), like this:
[image]

Here is my code

```
    # Build Pie Chart
poll = [6.8, 30.5, 62.7]
SnackType = ['Candy', 'Chips & Crackers', 'Healthy']
Colors = ['gold',"violet", 'green']
explode= [0, 0, .1]


plt.pie(poll, labels=SnackType, colors=Colors, explode=explode, shadow=True, startangle=150)
plt.title("% of favorite snacks")

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

My quick solution was to add

```
plt.axis("auto")
```

However, it'd still like to be able to control the tilt.  Preferably, I'd like to make it look more tilted.

Comment: Well, that doesn't exactly make it look *tilted*, but rather *squeezed*. However, if that is the kind of adaption you want to make, you can just set the limits, `plt.ylim(-2,2)`, change the numbers to whatever you like.